# localhost sent an invalid response flask

Tags: python, html, flask, localhost, host

this is my main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from oauth import Oauth

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')

@app.route("/")
def home():
  return render_template("index.html",discord_url=Oauth.discord_login_url)

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return "Success"

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(debug=True)
```

my index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Home Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to Hexon X dashboard!</h1>
    Click here to login:
    <a href="{{discord_url}}"><button>Login with discord</button></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

my oauth.py

```
class Oauth:
    client_id = "Secret"
    client_secret = "Secret "
    redirect_uri = "https://127.0.0.1:5000/login"
    scope = "identify%20email%20guilds"
    discord_login_url = "secret too"
    discord_token_url = "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token"
    discord_api_url = "https://discord.com/api"
```

Give me this error

`127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response`

can someone help me with that
the return URL doesn't work
and it doesn't return success after redirected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am right, the only problem which i see here is `redirect_uri = "https://127.0.0.1:5000/login"`. localhost only works with `http` not `https` (though we can make it to work in https, but in most of the cases, we don't need to do so). So try changing this and see if it works.